# Question about a Sobolev norm

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces

The Sobolev seminorm on $H^s$ is
$$|f| = \int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^{2}}{|x-y|^{n+2s-1}}dxdy$$
My question is, is this integral a double integral or a iterated integral?

i.e. can I integrate one variable first and then the other, so can I write 
$$\int_{\Omega}\int_{\Omega} \frac{f(x)g(y)}{|x-y|^{n+2s-1}}dxdy=\int_{\Omega}\bigg(\int_{\Omega} \frac{f(x)}{|x-y|^{n+2s-1}}dx\bigg)g(y)dy$$
and then use a bound on the inner integral and a fact that $g \in L^1$ to show that $\tilde{f}\tilde{g}$ has finite $H^s$ seminorm, where $|\tilde f \tilde g|_{H^s}$ is less than the left hand side of the above equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can integrate (the first integral) with respect to $x$ and $y$ in any order you want. This is an implication of Fubini's Theorem.

Unfortunately, what you suggest to do next is not a good idea, as the difference ratio of the first integral has much better chances to be integrable, than if you split it expanding $|f(x)-g(x)|^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is better phrased like this: suppose I have shown that $\int_{\Omega}\big(\int_{\Omega} \frac{|h(x)-h(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2s-1}}dx\big)dy < \infty$, for a function $h:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}.$ Does this imply that that $f \in H^s(\Omega)$ (assuming $f \in L^2$)? Note that I calculated the iterated integral above, I don't know if I can do that to say the seminorm is finite because I can't use Fubini and I don't know if the seminorm is defined as iterated integral or double integral..

Comment: @michael_carbon You are integrating a *nonnegative* function, [Tonelli's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem) applies.